# finding PCI domain number for extended BDF

Tags: windows, fpga, pci, pci-e

I am trying to use `pyPCIE` to to access data in a RAM module on a FPGA board directly through PCIe. The `pyPCIE` package uses extended BDF notation `xxxx:06:00.1` to determine which device am I connecting to. I am able to find the BDF sections using `RW everything`, but I am having difficulty in finding the leading 16 bit PCI domain number.

I am currently working on a Windows 10 and Windows 7 machine.

Comment: In 99.9% cases on the desktops the domain is equal to 0, meaning `0000:06.00.1` for your example.